# Check box with autopostback = "true" inside of repeater, inside of UpdatePanel pops page back to top when clicked

Tags: c#, ajax, checkbox, updatepanel, repeater

I have an UpdatePanel that contains a repeater that basically builds  a list of checkboxes. Those check boxes are set to AutoPostback with an "OnCheckedChanged" event.

When the user checks a checkbox, everything happens as expected except for one thing, the page pops (or scrolls) back to the top.

Other controls that cause this UpdatePanel to refresh don't cause this issue, even just plain checkboxes that ARE NOT inside of my repeater, but still within the UpdatePAnel, work fine (no scroll back to top)...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open your page in designview (Source) at the top you will find pagedirectives

try adding    MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"

hope it helps !!!

Comment: Thanks Zia, this worked. I knew about this already, but it has caused some unpredicatble behavior for me in past projects so I avoid using it. But looking at verything closely, in this scenario, everything works fine :)